# Which mode for baking cake in microwave?

Tags: cake, grilling, microwave

I have a microwave over with a grill. Four modes of cooking are possible with this.

1. Microwave(with 100, 80, 60, 40 and 20% power)
2. Grill(heating coil is only at the top)
3. Combination 1(30% time for microwave and 70% time for grill)
4. Combination 2(55% time for microwave and 45% time for grill)

Is it possible to bake a cake using any of these modes and if possible which one will be the best option?

Comment: Microwave ovens are not ovens. Period. There are recipes designed to be "baked" in a microwave but it is not the same thing at all and, if you're not using one of those recipes, your results will likely be very poor. Do you not have an actual oven of any sort? See this explanation [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/7008/33128).

Answer (score 2):

There is not a straight "yes" or "no" answer to your question.

First, an oven which cannot turn off its microwaves cannot replace a normal oven. Any recipe meant to be baked in a real oven will fail if it is exposed to microwaves. So alternatives 1,3 and 4 are out. Option 2 also won't work, even if the microwaves are truly turned off, because the cake will not rise and stay raw in the middle. You cannot bake a cake without a bottom coil.

For the "yes" part, there are recipes which are specifically designed for microwaves. They are more muffin-like, and most of them have to be eaten while hot. Also, if you are making them, you have to give up on the whole variety of texture which is possible with cakes and make this one specific type. But if that's enough for you, do it. You will have to search recipe databases for "microwave cupcake". Just don't try to take a random cake recipe and bake it in the microwave.

If you try a microwave specific recipe, then the pure microwave setting will be the correct one. The power choice will be given by the recipe.

For some more detail, see also [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17662/baking-cakes-in-the-microwave-ovens-as-compared-to-electric-ovens?rq=1), [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44376/how-to-bake-a-cake-in-a-microwave-oven?rq=1) and [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21805/can-these-settings-bake-a-cake).